# Entity Framework automated join

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I don't think the title of my question is pretty accurate so I'll try to explain what my problem is . 
I have 2 models : Article and User

```
public class Article
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User Author { get; set; }
    public int Likes { get; set; }
} 
public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Article> MyArticles { get; set; }
    }
```

and my database context

```
public class Context: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way to list my Articles in a view and access data from the Users model (table) ?
Example : If I pass `var mode = db.Articles` through the controller 
can I make something like

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
     <p>item.Title</p>
     <p>item.Content</p>
     <p>item.Author.Name</p>
}
```

I'm pretty sure rails has this possibility and I thought  EF 4.1 had it too .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is an instance of `User` then you could use the following in your view:

```
foreach(var article in Model.MyArticles) {
    <p>article.Title</p>
    <p>article.Content</p>
    <p>article.Author.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it gives me this error _CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EFTests.Models.User>' does not contain a definition for 'MyArticles' and no extension method 'MyArticles' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EFTests.Models.User>' could be found _

Comment: That's because you need to pass in a single user into the view. Otherwise you need to iterate over the users in the model and change my code to use that user from your outer loop

Answer (score 1):

First of all load User and Article (if you use lazy loading you can skip this step):

```
var users = context.Users
    .Include(u => u.MyArticles)                      
    .ToList();
```

Than in your view pass the users list:

```
foreach(var user in Model)
{
   <h2>@user.name</h2>
   foreach(var article in user.MyArticles) {   
      <p>@article.Title</p>   
      <p>@article.Content</p>   
      <p>@article.Author.Name</p>   
   }
}
```

Comment: I get an "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. " error . Any ideas ?

Comment: OK I found out ! I need to set MultipleActiveResultSets=true in my connection string . :D